# How many binary sequences of length n will contain exactly 3 digits that are 0's?

Tags: combinatorics

I came up with this.

We have C(1,1) = 1 ways to choose 0's, and then we multiply it by C(n,3) so that we have three of them. Does this seem correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I do not see necessity to choose $0$'s. The rest is ok.

Comment: Agreed.  The generalized solution has absolutely no reason to make any reference to "*choosing zeroes.*"  The number of binary sequences of length $n$ which contain exactly $k$ zeroes is very simply $\binom{n}{k}$ and is one of most common interpretations of the binomial coefficient with perhaps the most common being the number of $k$-element subsets of an $n$-element set.  It should be clear why the count is the same for both scenarios if you consider the set as the positions available in your sequence and the subset as the positions which contain $0$'s.